# Ruby - Why use "until" when "while" can do the same

Tags: ruby

This is the code using `while`:

```
i = 0
num = 5

while i < num do
   puts "Inside the loop! i = #{i}"
   i += 1
end
```

This is the code using `until`:

```
i = 0
num = 5

until i > num do
   puts "Inside the loop! i = #{i}"
   i += 1
end
```

Can someone give an example of when one should be preferred instead of the other? For me, there is no reason to have `until` *and* `while` if they do the same thing. In my opinion, this is the reason why other programming languages don't have both.

Comment: $variables are global, you should avoid using them in Ruby.  Also your programs have different output.

Comment: Why use loops when `goto` can do the same? Because it yields more readable, maintainable code.

Comment: `while i < num` is not the same as `until i > num`...

Comment: Ruby having both "until" and "while" is similar to it having both "unless" and "if".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's about readability. A "correct" example is *completely* subjective:

```
done = my_function until done
```

or

```
done = false
until done
 # better than "while not done"? Who can say?
 # do something that modifies the state of done
end
```

or

```
my_object.do_something until my_object.complete
# Or, if the method were otherwise named...
my_object.do_something while my_object.incomplete
```

Answer (score 16):

Which is better:

1. `makeSoup while !ingredients.empty?`
2. `makeSoup until ingredients.empty?`

`while` and `until` do the same thing, one is just "nicer" to read in some instances.